# How to specify client version with JClouds-Chef?

Tags: java, chef-infra, jclouds

I have been using the following [JClouds-Chef 1.7.3](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-chef) code for several months now to bootstrap new VMs from scratch:

```
public class Bootstrapper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bootstrapper b = new Bootstrapper();
        b.bootstrap();
    }

    public void bootstrap() {
        String endpoint = "https://mychef.example.com"
        String client = "myuser"
        String validator = "chef-validator"

        String clientCredential = Files.toString(new File("/etc/myuser/myuser.pem"), Charsets.UTF_8)
        String validatorCredential = Files.toString(new File("/etc/myuser/chef-validator.pem"), Charsets.UTF_8)

        Properties props = new Properties()
        props.put(ChefProperties.CHEF_VALIDATOR_NAME, validator);
        props.put(ChefProperties.CHEF_VALIDATOR_CREDENTIAL, validatorCredential)
        props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_RELAX_HOSTNAME, "true")
        props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_TRUST_ALL_CERTS, "true")

        ChefContext ctx = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("chef")
            .endpoint(endpoint)
            .credentials(client, clientCredential)
            .overrides(props)
            .modules(ImmutableSet.of(new SshjSshClientModule())) //
            .buildView(ChefContext.class);

        ChefApi api = ctx.unwrapApi(ChefApi.class)
        MyEnvProvider environmentProvider = new MyEnvProvider()

        Environment devEnv = environmentProvider.provideEnvironment()
        api.createEnvironment(devEnv)

        List<String> runlist = new RunListBuilder().addRole("myrole").build()
        BootstrapConfig bootstrapConfig = BootstrapConfig.builder().environment("myenv").runList(runlist).build()

        String vmIp = "myapp01.example.com"
        String vmSshUsername = "myuser"
        String vmSshPassword = "12345"
        ChefService chef = chefContext.getChefService()
        chef.updateBootstrapConfigForGroup(chefGroup, bootstrapConfig)

        Statement bootstrap = chef.createBootstrapScriptForGroup(chefGroup)

        SshClient.Factory sshFactory = chefContext.unwrap().utils()
            .injector().getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<SshClient.Factory>() {}))

        SshClient ssh = sshFactory.create(HostAndPort.fromParts(vmIp, 22),
        LoginCredentials.builder().user(vmSshUsername).password(vmSshPassword).build())

        ssh.connect()

        StringBuilder rawScript = new StringBuilder()

        Map<String, String> resolvedFunctions = ScriptBuilder.resolveFunctionDependenciesForStatements(
            new HashMap<String, String>(), ImmutableSet.of(bootstrap), OsFamily.UNIX)

        ScriptBuilder.writeFunctions(resolvedFunctions, OsFamily.UNIX, rawScript)
        rawScript.append(bootstrap.render(OsFamily.UNIX))

        ssh.put("/tmp/chef-bootstrap.sh", rawScript.toString())
        ExecResponse result = ssh.exec("sudo bash /tmp/chef-bootstrap.sh")

        ssh.disconnect()
        api.close()
        ctx.close()
    }
}
```

I just ran this code for the first time in several weeks, and everything is broken. It seems this code now results with nodes that use Chef 12, whereas `mychef.example.com` is a Chef 11 server, and this is the root of the issue.

So I ask: **How do I configure this code so that it continues to install/bootstrap Chef 11.x nodes?**

**Please note:** This is a *code* question, *not* a systems admin question, and as such belong on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jclouds docs list how to configure the process](https://jclouds.apache.org/guides/chef/).

In this case you would want something like `ChefProperties.CHEF_VERSION = '11.16.4'`. I feel like I should point out that chef-client 12 works just fine with Chef Server 11. If you are running Enterprise Chef 11 you just need to update a config variable on it to allow client 12, as it was incorrectly limited to only 11.x.

Comment: Take into account that starting from jclouds 1.7, Chef is installed by default using the Omnibus installer, and that will install the latest version of the Chef client, regardless of the `ChefProperties.CHEF_VERSION` property value. (BTW, is there a way to install via the Omnibus script a concrete version of the Chef client?). If you want to control the exact Chef version that is installed, you need to set the `ChefProperties.USE_OMNIBUS` to `false` and configure the properties @coderanger mentioned accordingly.

Comment: Yep, pass a [`-v option`](https://github.com/opscode/opscode-omnitruck/blob/master/views/install.sh.erb#L72) when running the script. Also remember you can set it to things like `11` to get the latest 11.x release.

Comment: Thanks @coderanger! I've just created a patch to add support for the custom version (by setting the same `CHEF_VERSION` property) when using the Omnibus installer. You can expect it to be available in short: https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/pull/638

Comment: if I configure both `chefConfig.put(ChefProperties.CHEF_USE_OMNIBUS, false); chefConfig.put(ChefProperties.CHEF_VERSION,"11.16.4");` its not downloading the chef client rpm from chef url ... any ideas ?